# Парсинг телеграм бота, с добавлением в базу данных

Tags: python, aiogram, telethon

В телеграм бота шлются с парсера заявки. Как эти заявки парсить с телеграмм аккаунта и закидывать в базу данных? Возможно ли такое? Если да, то какую библиотеку использовать

Answer (score 0):

Есть возможность парсить заявки, которые отправляются из аккаунтов Telegram, и загружать их в базу данных. Один из способов добиться этого — использовать библиотеку python-telegram-bot, которая позволяет создавать ботов Telegram и взаимодействовать с API Telegram.

Во-первых, вам нужно создать бота, поговорив с BotFather и получить токен.

Затем вы можете использовать MessageHandler для обработки сообщений, содержащих приложения, и извлекать из сообщения необходимую информацию.

Затем вы можете использовать библиотеку sqlite3 для подключения к базе данных SQLite и вставки извлеченных данных в соответствующую таблицу.

Вот пример того, как вы можете обработать сообщение, содержащее приложение, и вставить информацию в базу данных SQLite:

```
import sqlite3
from telegram.ext import Updater, MessageHandler, Filters

def handle_application(bot, update):
    message = update.message
    name = message.text
    conn = sqlite3.connect('applications.db')
    c = conn.cursor()
    c.execute("INSERT INTO applications (name) VALUES (?)")
```

Если я ошибаюсь то прошу поправить